# Django function parse_duration() cannot parse years or months

Tags: django, timedelta

I am trying to parse the ISO 8601 duration `P1Y` or `P1M`, representing one year or one month respectively, using the `parse_duration()` function of the `django.utils.dateparse` module. The returned value though is `None`. The documentation of the function says that it supports ISO 8601 durations. But it seems that it supports the standard without the years or months, because I can successfully parse the duration `P2DT12H60M33S`, resulting in a `timedelta` object of 2 days and 46833 seconds. Is this a bug, a feature or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the source code of [dateparse.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/dateparse.py) module:

> ```
> # Support the sections of ISO 8601 date representation that are accepted by
> # timedelta
> iso8601_duration_re = re.compile(
>     r'^(?P<sign>[-+]?)'
>     r'P'
>     r'(?:(?P<days>\d+(.\d+)?)D)?'
>     r'(?:T'
>     r'(?:(?P<hours>\d+(.\d+)?)H)?'
>     r'(?:(?P<minutes>\d+(.\d+)?)M)?'
>     r'(?:(?P<seconds>\d+(.\d+)?)S)?'
>     r')?'
>     r'$'
> )
>
> # Support PostgreSQL's day-time interval format, e.g. "3 days 04:05:06". The
> # year-month and mixed intervals cannot be converted to a timedelta and thus
> # aren't accepted.
> postgres_interval_re = re.compile(
>     r'^'
>     r'(?:(?P<days>-?\d+) (days? ?))?'
>     r'(?:(?P<sign>[-+])?'
>     r'(?P<hours>\d+):'
>     r'(?P<minutes>\d\d):'
>     r'(?P<seconds>\d\d)'
>     r'(?:\.(?P<microseconds>\d{1,6}))?'
>     r')?$'
> )
> ```

The first regular expression is for parsing the ISO 8601 durations. As the comment above `iso8601_duration_re` states, only the sections of ISO 8601 duration that are accepted by the `timedelta` are supported. Where `timedelta` supports only *weeks, days, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds* and *microseconds*. This is clearly stated also in the comment above the `postgres_interval_re`:

> The year-month and mixed intervals cannot be converted to a timedelta and thus aren't accepted.

The fact that years or months are not supported, can be also proved by examining the source code. For example the code for the `iso8601_duration_re` regular expression has parsing instructions only for *days, hours, minutes* and *seconds*. There are no instructions for years or months.

I think that there is a reason for not supporting months and years, since their duration is ambiguous. A month can be either *28,29,30* or *31* days and a year can be either *365* or *366* days. This ambiguity is allowed in the ISO 8601, but not allowed in the `timedelta` object (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29458514/4501084)). This is because internally it stores the duration in *days, seconds* and *microseconds* (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta)) and therefore a `timedelta` of *1 year*, for example, could be either *365 days, 0 seconds* and *0 microseconds* or *366 days, 0 seconds* and *0 microseconds*.

Comment: A day can also be 23 or 25 hours, and a minute can be 60 or 61 seconds in case of leap seconds. This is just lazy design.