# Is there a standard way to represent a time duration, time-span or time-delta?

Tags: text-formatting

If we accept that there are various standard ways to represent times and dates, is there a standard way to present a time-span or time-delta? I would add the requirement that the presentation of the time-span should also be amenable to parsing.

For example is Days/HH:MM:SS.FFFFFF (E.g. 3/14:12:04.201000 ) acceptable?
With HH : Hours, MM : Minutes, SS : Seconds, FFFFFFF fraction of a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISO 8601 defines *durations* of the form

```
P...Y...M...DT...H...M...S
```

where `...` are numbers and

- P (period) marks the string as a duration
- Y years
- M months
- D days
- T (time) resolves ambiguity between months and minutes
- H hours
- M minutes
- S seconds

Components with value 0 can be left out as long as there is at least one component (e.g. `PT5S` denotes 5 seconds). The least significant component can have a fractional value (e.g. `PT0.5H` denotes half an hour = 30 minutes).

However, ISO 8601 defined these durations for specifying time intervals of the form `start_date_time + duration`. Depending on the start date and time, the length of every component but `S` might vary.

- Years can have 365 or 366 days for leap years.
- Months can have between 28 and 31 days.
- Days can have 23 to 25 hours when changing daylight saving time.
- Minutes can have 60 or 61 seconds for leap seconds.

See also [What is the value of the ISO 8601 duration `P1M` (in seconds)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26265751/6770384). ISO 8601 mentiones that *some* applications *may* fix durations like `P1M` = `P30D` and so on, but does not *define* it at all.

To work around these interpretation problems, you could use seconds only, e.g. `PT3600S` instead of `PT1H` (the standard does *not* enforce carry-over points like 60s, 24h and so on). However, that seems pretty pointless. I'd rather just use the number in seconds without `PT` and `S` (unix-time style) or switch to a non-standardized (?) but abundant format like you suggested (video timestamps).